# Is it safe to use multiple OutputStream for the same Socket?

Tags: java, sockets

Is this piece of code safe to use? I'm used to making one `PrintWriter` or reader per socket, but now I'm in this situation where I have to pass sockets like this, so I'm asking if I need to close them after each send or worry about any memory problems or damaging the socket in the long run?

```
    public static void sayHello(Socket socket)
    {
        try{

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            out.println("HELLO !");
            out.flush();

        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't safe, unless you are religious about flushing, and unless all access to the various streams/writers is sequentialized so that they cannot possibly interleave when they auto-flush themselves. In general this is difficult enough to accomplish that it's simpler not to use multiple streams in the first place. You should construct a single pair of streams (input and output) and use them for the life of the socket.