# How to change the super of a class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'll explain my issue in a code example. I have this static method called `getNewBaby()` (that I can not change) it only returns a `Animal` class. I need someway to convert that animal to Dog. Here's my two failed attempts so far:

```
public static class Animal
{
    public void eat(){}
}

public static class Dog extends Animal
{
    public Dog(Animal animal)
    {
        super = animal; // <-- error 1
    }
    public void bark(){}
}
```

.

```
public static Animal getNewBaby()
{
    return new Animal( /* some future parameters */ );
}

public static void main()
{
    //Attempt number 1:
    Dog puppy1 = (Dog)(getNewBaby());  //  <-- error 2

    //Attempt number 2:
    Dog puppy2 = new Dog(getNewBaby());  //  <-- error 3
}
```

How can I fix this without changing anything in `getNewBaby()` method ?

Comment: `public static class Animal` , `public static class Dog extends Animal`  Are these inner classes?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you don't control `getNewBaby()`, how can you be so sure it is a `Dog`?

Comment: @TheLostMind no, I get errors `Animal cannot be cast to Dog`, etc..
@Joffrey It's not a dog, but I want to make it one, to convert it somehow

Comment: Unless Animal and the other classes are static inner classes, why are you using `static`on those class declarations? If not you should remove the `static` from the `public static class Animal` and all other class declarations as a first step.

Comment: @Omoro If all those classes are declared in the same file (Main I presume), they'd better be static. Of course, for a larger scale program, the OP will need to separate them, and remove `static`.

Comment: I'm just using this inside a simple Main.java example. If I remove the `static` keyword it would not even compile, I get this weird error: `No enclosing instance of type Main is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Main (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Main).`

Comment: What would you do with an `Animal` that you make a `Dog`? What's the larger logic of your program? If the method `getNewBaby()` does not produce cats and dogs, then you won't have cats and dogs attributes, so you won't be able to use them fully as dogs or cats.

Comment: @Joffrey Because I use `ServerSocket.accept()` (as `getNewBaby()` in my example) that just returns `Socket` class once a connexion is accepted. But I want to convert the Socket to an `EasySocket` class I made which has some more extra features to enables easy read and write with single streams etc..

Comment: @Heidi That conceptually changes everything! You should have posted your original use case in the first place, believe me ;-) If your "extra features" are like wrapper methods that do macro operations on the socket, then using composition is fine. I'll post a new answer in a second.

Comment: @Heidi Have a look at my new answer, this'll probably suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new information you have just posted as a comment (which *really* needs to be emphasized), here is a probably suitable solution for you.

This solution uses *composition* instead of *inheritance*. This means your custom class does not `extend` the original class, but *contains* an instance of it, and uses it internally.

I used to discourage you from using composition because of the Animal-Dog example, which was conceptually wrong, but here is a different use case, so a different answer ;-)

```
public class EasySocket {

    private Socket socket;

    public EasySocket(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    /* 
     * Here are your helper methods that use socket's methods: for instance, use 
     * socket.getInputStream() instead of simply getInputStream(), since you don't inherit
     * from the Socket class anymore. 
     */
}
```

Then when you receive a `Socket` object:

```
Socket socket = someServerSocket.accept();
EasySocket easySocket = new EasySocket(socket);
// use easySocket
```

Comment: haha! That is exactly what I ended up doing! The only drawback to this is I can not use class inheritance to simply override methods I need. I also can not store my EasySocket class in my old `ArraList<Socket>` arrays (by casting them back and forth), so I had to rewrite a big part of the code. But it's no big deal it works great and it solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Heidi I'm glad you found the solution. Yeah I don't think there's a better way to accomplish what you want. But out of curiosity, what methods of `Socket` would you want to override?

Comment: Thank you! I added a bunch of "read(string) and write(string)" methods to the socket, and added a file log capability but had to make sure the streams close properly when disconnected (also logging disconnect time too), but most importantly I needed this to embed a single StreamWriter and Reader per socket as discussed here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271145/is-it-safe-to-use-multiple-outputstream-for-the-same-socket/26272164#26272164)

Comment: If you want to store instances of multiple different objects in an Array list,  and access some common methods they both contain,  I would strongly recommend using Interfaces.  This allows you to avoid casting,  which is a dangerous game in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is impossible: you cannot re-initialize `super`.

However there are alternatives (assuming you cannot modify `getNewBaby`):

- Enclose your down-casting in a `try` / `catch` statement and catch a `ClassCastException`
- Use `instanceof` to check on the actual type, whether it's `Animal`, `Dog`, `Cat`, etc. and base your logic on that
- **Best choice** declare methods in `Animal` that can be overridden on all child classes, thus de-coupling implementation

**Edit**

Here are a couple of additional topics - a bit off/broad, but might help you with your design.

- Java [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and casting
- The [factory pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) in Java
- Java [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: The OPs classes are all public *static*, I guess he / she needs to change the signature too :).

Comment: @TheLostMind that doesn't change much. It only means they are bound to the whichever class they are declared into.

Comment: @TheLostMind that does not mean they are `final`

Comment: @Joffrey - I didn't say that *static* makes them *final*.

Comment: @TheLostMind it looked like you were saying the last solution was not possible, my bad if that's not what you meant ;-)

Comment: @TheLostMind what Joffrey says :)

Comment: @Mena - I was merely pointing out that she will still end up with compilation errors if she didn't remove *static* :)

Comment: @TheLostMind where from? Having trouble understanding you here.

Comment: @TheLostMind same here, what compile errors are you talking about?

Comment: @Mena --> `public static class Animal` and `public static class Dog extends Animal` unless they are *inner* classes (I don't think so).

Comment: @TheLostMind I see. I would assume they are, and OP just didn't post the whole code for brevity. For instance there's a `main` method, apparently on the same nesting level than the `static` classes.

Comment: @TheLostMind They're probably all in the OPs `Main` class file, along with his `main()` method. So they are probably inner classes. This is discussed in the question's comments already ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you why some things are wrong, but without more information about where you're going, we can't help you reorganize your code, though.

#### Bad constructor pattern

The following is just wrong with respect to inheritance:

```
public Dog(Animal animal) {
    //...
}
```

`Dog` should not *need* an `Animal` to be created, because it *Is-A* `Animal`, which makes sense here. 
Such a construct would be more in accordance to [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), but it wouldn't be appropriate here, and you would need to remove `extends Animal` on the `Dog` class.

#### Affectation of `super`

The following is not possible in Java because `super` is just a way of referring to `this` object as an object from the super class. You can't reaffect `this` either, because you *are* currently this object.

```
super = animal; // <-- error 1
```

#### About the cast fail

Casting an `Animal` to a `Dog` means that you *know* the object is indeed a `Dog`, and you want the compiler to assume it (cast is needed because of Java strong typing).

Here your `getNewBaby()` method returns an `Animal` object, not a subclass of it, so won't be able to cast it to `Dog` (`ClassCastException` at runtime) because it is simply an `Animal` (which does not make sense, by the way. `Animal` should be abstract).

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in very simple words I can understand !  So you mean to say, it is not possible in Java to create a dog, with an exact copy of an animal class ? (exact, as in, same reference etc)

Comment: If you write `new Dog()` somewhere, then you'll have a `Dog` object, which is **also** an `Animal` object (you'll be able to call methods from both classes on it). But you can't get a `Dog` object from an `Animal` created by `new Animal(...)`.

Comment: Yes but, I want Dog to wrap over an existing animal. Not possible ? No possible way around it ?

Comment: Everything is possible, what you're talking about sounds like composition (see link in my answer). But composition is more for an *HAS-A* relationship. Do you think a `Dog` *HAS-AN* `Animal`, or *IS-AN* `Animal`? *IS-A* makes more sense here, that's why you should use inheritance, and thus you can't create a Dog from an existing plain Animal.

Comment: It seems like a very complicated subject, I understand a little bit better now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I understood your requirement correctly, you can do the following. Instead of trying to assign `animal` object to `super`, assign values in `animal` object to corresponding variables in Dog's super class.

```
public static class Animal
{
    public Animal() {}
    public int parameter1 =0;

    public Animal(int param1){
        this.parameter1 = param1;
    }

    public void eat(){}
}

public static class Dog extends Animal
{
    public Dog(Animal animal) //This is not nice
    {
        super.parameter1 = animal.parameter1;
    }
    public void bark(){}
}
```

.

```
public static Animal getNewBaby()
{
    return new Animal( 4 /*Some integer value for parameter1*/ );
}

public static void main()
{
    Dog puppy2 = new Dog(getNewBaby());
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the same reference for the new `Dog`, which can't be achieved. Although, your solution to "copy" the animal is a good workaround for the OP's problem, I think there is a larger design problem here, which we can't improve without better knowledge of the OP's objectives.

Comment: Good idea. Sadly it won't work for me as I need it to wrap over a more complicated Socket class with a lot more dependencies. The Animal/Dog example helps me illustrate the issue I'm facing to explain it a little bit better